# trouble when testing solidity with web3 ^1.0.0-beta.37

Tags: solidity

I got error "lottery contract 1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract" " & " 1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const provider = ganache.provider()
const web3 = new Web3(provider)

const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

let Lottery;
let accounts;

beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    Lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: bytecode })
        .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'})
})

describe('lottery contract', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
        assert.ok(Lottery.options.address)
    })
})

  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.4.3",
    "solc": "^0.4.17",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.13",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^6.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: the bottom code is from package-json. I should have separate it.

Comment: i fixed it by uninstalling web3 and then reinstalling web3 with version ^1.0.0-beta.37. ..... haha.......